# ATI proprietary drivers for "old" devices

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ati, graphics, radeon

I have noticed that my Ubuntu installation is quite sluggish and slow despite the fact that the hardware is not so old (a dual core 2.40GHz CPU 4GB of ram and a Mobility Radeon HD 3650 graphic card)

I have strong evidence to suspect this is related to the fact that the recent releases of Ubuntu use the OS driver for this graphic card.

Hence I would like to install the proprietary driver as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI) but it appears that the latest release of fglrx does not support my graphic card

```
jernej@darkstar:~$ sudo aticonfig --initial
[sudo] password for jernej: 
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected
```

Hence I am wondering - what would be the best way to install the proprietary driver in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a real bad situation, and there's little you can do to actually "fix" the problem but keep complaining to AMD.

There are ways to bypass it though:

1) Play with OpenGL settings in CompizConfig (available thru Software Center): uncheck VSync, use Fast texture filter, try to uncheck frame/vertex buffers.

2) You can try Unity 2D.

3) You can try Xubuntu/Lubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried any of the above?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend downloading the AMD Catalyst Legacy driver from the AMD site found [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy2&os=Linux%20x86_64) (for x86_64) and follow the installation guide as described in the 3.1 section of the Ubuntu wiki page you are quoting.

My brother has a laptop with an AMD Mobility Radeon HD4650 (not supported by the latest driver) and has been using the same driver without any problems, following the guide from Ubuntu wiki.

Cheers.

Comment: The problem is that these drivers are only supported for kernel versions up to 3.4 :(

Comment: You did not mention that you have >3.4 kernel version. Why don't you try Ubuntu 12.04 with 3.2 kernel?

Comment: The thing is that then I am forced to stay with it and never update over to kernels > 3.4

Comment: To stay with what? What Ubuntu version are you using? What is the output of the command `uname -r`?

Comment: @Jernej you either update your kernel and the thing that doesn't allow you to update the kernel or you are stuck with them. Either way you must give such details in the question.

Comment: @Jernej I guess AMD updates their legacy driver from time to time. Perhaps they'll do it when Ubuntu 14.04 is released. Until then, you'll be forced to stay with Ubuntu 12.04... :( Otherwise you will have to use open driver.